# Почему не срабатывает условие if is_tax в дочерних категориях Таксаномии WP?

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php if (is_tax('buildings', 'type-a')) { ?>
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/floorplan/level/floorplan_a_2-9.png">
 <?php } elseif (is_tax('buildings', 'type-b')) { ?>
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/floorplan/level/floorplan_b_2-9.png">
<?php } ?>
```

Срабатывает только в родительской категории "type-a" и "type-b" в taxanomy "buildings" в дочерних категория не работает buildings/type-a/дочерняя-категория не срабатывает подскажите пожалуйста как решить ?

Answer (score 0):

Потому-что она для этого не предназначена, чтобы проверить дочернюю категорию способов много, вот пример с учетом того что вы находитесь на странице таксономии:

```
$currentCategory = get_queried_object();
$parentCategory = getParentCat($currentCategory->term_id,'buildings');
function getParentCat($term_id, $taxonomy) {
    if (isset($term_id)) {
        $parent = get_term_by('id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
        while ($parent->parent != 0) {
            $parent = get_term_by('id', $parent->parent, $taxonomy);
        }
        return $parent;
    }
    return false;
}

if (in_array($parentCategory->slug, ['type-a', 'type-b'])) {
    //  что-то
} else {
    // что-то
}
```

Comment: Не могу проверить так как не получается добавить картинку через echo, как его туда подставить ? можно ваш варинат как то совместить с моим вариантов изображения ?, чтоб можно было просто вот так поставить, <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/floorplan/level/floorplan_a_2-9.png"> ?

Comment: ваш вариант к сожалению не сработал (((((((((((